# Cannot convert value 'Detailed' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I got an error when I open an existing build definition and select Process

> Parameter Logging Verbosity: cannot convert value 'Detailed' of type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity to type Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildVerbosity, reset to default.

I am using VS 2012 connect to TFS2012. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please share the relevant code with us. Otherwise it is difficult (if not impossible) to help you with that issue.

Comment: There's c# code.  It may related to build template xaml file. I googled that error, but didn't find useful info. What could be the reason of that error?

Comment: @calif Did you upgrade build definition and open it in VS 2012? If so, you can refer to this article about how to upgrade build definition. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpricket/2012/10/24/upgrading-your-build-definitions-from-tfs2010-to-tfs2012/) If not, you can share your build definition on the OneDrive and I will check it.

Comment: Can you share the build definition template?